# How can I pass parameters to getter in Sequelize model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, getter

**What I'm doing:**

I'm reading csv which contains data like *townships*, *religions* and so on. In the csv, they are **text** values. But of course in my table in the database, they are `foreign_key`. So to insert those, I need to map those **text** values to **id**.

It is possible to get the **id** like below.

```js
const { townshipId } = await models.Township.findOne({
    where: { name: township },
    attributes: ["townshipId"],
    raw: true,
});
```

**The problem:**

But the problem what I think is that those `findOne`(s) will be populated in my entire method because I have like 50 other properties besides **township**.

**What I'm trying**

I'm trying to pass `township-name` to a `getter` method, expecting its **equivalent townshipId**.

I found out that it is possible to use [`getter` and `setter`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html) in sequelize. But I don't find how to pass parameters to those.

**My question**

Am I trying the correct way to import the csv data? How can I use getters (and setters) with parameters in sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you want to exclude columns from the result, you pass the "attributes" field like:

`attributes: { exclude: ['field1','field2'] }`

This way you wont show the columns "field1" and "field2" in the result.